# How to add css to a part of xml?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part, xml

I have xml code very similar to this:

```
function _setDefaultResources() {
var el = $(".ms-acal-rootdiv");
var xml ='\u003cEntities Append=\u0022True\u0022 Error=\u0022\u0022

DoEncodeErrorMessage=\u0022True\u0022 Separator=\u0022;\u0022 MaxHeight=\u00223\u0022\u003e\u003cEntity

Key=\u0022TARRANTCOUNTY\\soeagleton\u0022 DisplayText=\u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton\u0022

IsResolved=\u0022True\u0022

Description=\u0022TARRANTCOUNTY\\soeagleton\u0022\u003e\u003cExtraData\u003e\u003cArrayOfDictionaryEntry

xmlns:xsi=\u0022http:\u002f\u002fwww.w3.org\u002f2001\u002fXMLSchema-instance\u0022

xmlns:xsd=\u0022http:\u002f\u002fwww.w3.org\u002f2001\u002fXMLSchema\u0022\u003e\u003cDictionaryEntry\u003
```

the part above: `DisplayText=\u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton\u0022`

**u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton**
How can I give the name CSS or just make it red and bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add CSS for XML at Specific Tag , try to do the following

- Create your CSS
- Add the CSS code per your tagName in XML (for example in XML `<Display>\u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton\u0022 </Display>` )

**CSS Code**

```
Display 
{
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: Red !important;
}
```

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="CSSFILENAME.css"?>
<Display>\u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton\u0022 </Display>
```

**Note :** You should be aware of Formatting XML with CSS is not recommended. Use JavaScript or XSLT instead.For more details check [How to add style to XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp)

In case of , you render the output to control with this class name `.ms-acal-rootdiv` Try to use the following style

```
<style>
.ms-acal-rootdiv div {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: Red !important;
}

.ms-acal-rootdiv {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: Red !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: M.Qassas you're awesome thank you. 2 quick relative questions if I may:
1: What if all entries had DisplayText=\u0022Sheryl O. Eagleton\u0022 where DisplayText is the commonality however it's only a few that I want to make formatted, Can some of those select few be DisplayTextSpecial instead of DisplayText and just apply css to DisplayTextSpecial or will that break code?
2: Because they are all concatenated is there a way to put some sort of commenting or delimiter that can be a visual for when one block of code starts and the other begins? Thank you. I am VERY grateful for your kindness.

Comment: Dear @MikeRooker, I am sorry for late , I think you can do it via class attribute  for example if the attached CSS file for XML has class called .class1 you can add a specific style for a specific content of a specific note as the following <p class="class1"> the note content </node> I am pretty sure this article will help you https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/004/doc.xml , please Mike don't hesitate to ask me if you need any clarification

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas, I am VERY grateful. I aplogize I can't grasp how to isolate some of the "DisplayText" that I want in red. I changed the name from DisplayText to DisplayText2 but it breaks the code. The example link unfortunately I could not make sense on how to apply that to the initial code. Once again, my sincere thanks for any help.